# Possible to SQL Server database drive a Google Map by UK postcode?

Tags: sql-server, database, google-maps, dynamic, postal-code

We have a property/accommodation profile page that lists a property address including postcode. This information is stored in a SQL Server database table and the page has a recordset that allows us to feed profile information onto a page depending on the propertyID that is selected (either via link or using a form) by the user.

We created a field in the database table that would allow us to insert the Google Map embed code for a property and, subsequently, we'd then call that on the property profile page but this requires us to create the embed code in Google Maps first, have to paste that into our database field etc, before it would display a map on our page.

So...we would like to database drive the map based on the postcode. Is that possible?

We really don't want to have to get into longitude/latitude coordinates, we just want the map to identify the postcode and put a place marker on a map where that postcode appears.

How do we acheive this?  We've tried looking through the documentation and help files, but we really don't know what we're asking for so finding answers is proving incredibly difficult or the answers that we've found seem extremely technical (Google API, Geocoding, etc) for what we're trying to acheive.

Could someone point us in the right direction?

We hoped that there would be some way of inserting the postcode, dynamically, into generic embed code from Google Maps and that Google Maps would do the rest.

Anyway, we would appreciate any help and advice that could be offered. Thank you.

Regards
NJ

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally Postcode data in the UK costs lots of money.

You can now download the Ordnance Survey data and convert their data into Latitude and longitude which would let you plot coordinates on google maps. (http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/code-point-open/index.html)

Comment: It doesn't cost any money to know a postcode. We have a list of property in our database and each one of those properties has a UK postcode. We basically just want to show a Google Map of the location, on a web page, that is driven by the postcode value from the database.  Perhaps this just isn't possible?

Comment: The coordinates of the postcode traditionally cost money though; the OS file will give you OS Coordinates and you can convert these to lat long for showing on a google map easily enough e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199308/convert-eastings-northings-to-latitude-longitude-using-nettopologysuite

Comment: We could search for the postcode using Google Maps and get the Lon/Lat coordinates...for free. That's very time consuming though, for 200+ locations. It's not really what we've asked though is it? We wanted to know if it is possible to drive a Google Map from a postcode. I'm assuming, from your response, that it's not which is why you've suggested converting to Lon/Lat?