# Convert easting and northing to latitude longitude cordinates

Tags: java, android

I have some easting and northing coordinates .. and I want to convert this coordinates to latitude longitude.. using java or android libraries.

any suggestions please

Comment: Try looking at this [previous post][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199308/convert-eastings-northings-to-latitude-longitude-using-nettopologysuite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is basically the reverse of [projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection). You need to know what projection your Eastings and Northings are in before you can do anything. Then you can apply the converse of the projection transformation to get Latitudes and Longitudes on a datum. You can either find the transformation (usually a fairly straightforward mathematical function, see the wikipedia link above) and implement it yourself, or use a 3rd-party library such as [Geotools](http://www.geotools.org/) or [GeoAPI](http://www.geoapi.org/index.html).

See also these two useful pages about the often-used Spherical Mercator:

[Spherical Mercator](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html) and [Google Maps Tiles](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) (Spherical Mercator section)

Comment: I have only `{
     "easting": "383643.108296",
     "latitude": null,
     "longitude": null,
     "northing": "398087.091274",
     "success": "1"
}`    I can display this on the Google map programmatically?

Comment: If it comes from a system that uses the same coordinate system as Google Maps, you should be able to with some function in the Google Maps API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). Where does the data come from?

Comment: See this question, one of the answers mentions some functions from GeoTools that may have a reverse that will be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313618/convert-latitude-and-longitude-to-northing-and-easting-in-java?rq=1

Comment: The data will indicate the location of the taxi but I not understand. why longitude and latitude empty, easting and northing not empty... And I'm starting to look for solutions .. and sings a question - if I can use that data to get a point on the map...

Comment: Longitude and Latitude refer to angles (hence are in Degrees) of inclination relative to the Equatorial plane and the Greenwich Meridian respectively. Eastings and Northings are concrete distances from the Equator and Prime Meridian respectively and thus are in meters or some other distance unit. Your data returns Eastings and Northings because the points are in a projected coordinate system. Normally one would convert from Lat/Lon to projected, but it is not complicated to do the reverse.